# Selecting text between borders using regexp in Go

Tags: regex, go

Sample of code:

```
proc := exec.Command(execString, arg01, arg02, arg03, arg04, arg05)
stdout, err := proc.Output()
res := string(stdout)
fmt.Printeln(res)
```

Stdout of this code:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'cuba'
+--- Project ':cuba-client'
+--- Project ':cuba-client-tests'
+--- Project ':cuba-core'
..........
```

I need to select ONLY projects'name, beetwen `':` and `'`, for this exaple:

```
cuba-client
cuba-client-tests
cuba-core
...........
```

I'm trying:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`':(.*?)'`)
reg := re.FindAllString(res, -1)
fmt.Println(reg)
```

And output:

```
':cuba-client'
':cuba-client-tests'
':cuba-core'
..............
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may use your pattern with [`FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch) and grab second items in the resulting array of matches. See https://play.golang.org/p/NHvCPntwFPL

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank yoy very much! It's work!